# Where are the Java 8 DateTimeFormatters constants defined?

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I am looking at the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and I was wondering where are the constants like `"M"`, `"EEE"` and `"YY"` etc are defined. More specifically there should be code like this somewhere given a [`ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) and [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html), it should return the `DateTimeFormatter` string snippet e.g. `(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, TextStyle.SHORT)` should map to the string `"MMM"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some source digging, I found out that these are pre-defined in a `private static final Map`, called `FIELD_MAP`, which is a member of the [DateTimeFormatBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#DateTimeFormatterBuilder.0FIELD_MAP) class:

```
 /** Map of letters to fields. */
private static final Map<Character, TemporalField> FIELD_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    // SDF = SimpleDateFormat
    FIELD_MAP.put('G', ChronoField.ERA);                       // SDF, LDML (different to both for 1/2 chars)
    FIELD_MAP.put('y', ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA);               // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('u', ChronoField.YEAR);                      // LDML (different in SDF)
    FIELD_MAP.put('Q', IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);             // LDML (removed quarter from 310)
    FIELD_MAP.put('q', IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);             // LDML (stand-alone)
    FIELD_MAP.put('M', ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);             // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('L', ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);             // SDF, LDML (stand-alone)
    FIELD_MAP.put('D', ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR);               // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('d', ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);              // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('F', ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);  // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('E', ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);               // SDF, LDML (different to both for 1/2 chars)
    FIELD_MAP.put('c', ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);               // LDML (stand-alone)
    FIELD_MAP.put('e', ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);               // LDML (needs localized week number)
    FIELD_MAP.put('a', ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY);               // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('H', ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);               // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('k', ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);         // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('K', ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM);              // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('h', ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM);        // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('m', ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);            // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('s', ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);          // SDF, LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('S', ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND);            // LDML (SDF uses milli-of-second number)
    FIELD_MAP.put('A', ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);              // LDML
    FIELD_MAP.put('n', ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND);            // 310 (proposed for LDML)
    FIELD_MAP.put('N', ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY);               // 310 (proposed for LDML)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a hack to get close without looking at the private field as @kocko mentioned:

```
String getFormat(ChornoField field, TextStyle style) {
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendText(field, style)
    .toString()  // This does not actually return the pattern but close enough??
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the original pattern given a `DateTimeFormatter` ?